# Are Brim & MGT Cache Extensions the Same?

Tags: extensions

http://www.mgt-commerce.com/speed-up-magento-by-full-page-cache.html
http://ecommerce.brimllc.com/full-page-cache-magento.html

See Brim left 'Benifits' against mgt right 'Benefits'.

$200 difference... hopefully somebody isnt getting ripped off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are just both Full Page Cache extensions, similar to what is shipped with Magento Enterprise.

They solve the same or at least similar problem to speed up pages with basically caching the full output.

This can be solved in many ways - so having to extensions with a similar goal does not mean they are exactly the same, or they have to have the same price tag.

Answer (score 0):

Developer of Brim's Full Page Cache here.

The code bases for the two extensions are completely separate, so they are different in that respect. However, they both are Full Page Caches and prevent Magento from generating a page from scratch on each request.

Our extension has a two level architecture. The first level is extremely fast but can only be used by visitors without anything in their cart. This first level hooks into an early event, preventing the need to load the vast majority of the Magento Core and any extensions you may have. So it's really fast sub 20ms, sub 10ms if you have a well tuned system. Hole punching or dynamic block updates are not supported on this level. If a customer is logged in or has items in their cart, then the second level or standard cache backend is used (which has full support for hole punching) and we support all the standard Magento blocks, like account links, side carts, etc. You can easily get sub 150ms page generations or sub 100ms on a tuned server. If you have any custom blocks that need to be hole punched, those can easily be setup by entering the block name into a field on the admin panel. Every setting is actually configurable via the admin panel. Those times are based on Magento page load times of .8-1.2 generation times w/o a full page cache.

Also just a few other benefits/features of ours are:

-100% open source

-A license covers all frontend domains run from one Magento install.

-Dead simple install, no core Magento files are ever touched.

-Redis support with Magento 1.8 CE+ or 1.13 EE+.

-Supports multiple currencies, stores, languages, mobile themes, etc.

-Cache any Magento rendered page. CMS, category, and product pages are all cached by 
default.

-Amazing support!

-Support is US based (benefit depending what timezone you are in).